# XPath : select only element when a value is lower than another in the same node

Tags: wordpress, xpath, wpallimport

i got a problem with my XPath. I need to select for WP ALL IMPORT only values that are lower than another value in the same node. In this case i need select nodes where values in search_price are lowests than rrp_price. I read every things on stackoverflow but nothing corresponds to this case. Can you help me ? I m scratching my head with operators but i can t find the good way. Thank you

My XPath base is /product

Example for one product :

`<product>
<rrp_price>
192.90
</rrp_price>
<search_price>
172.90
</search_price>
</product>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact structure of your xml, this xpath expression

```
//product[./search_price < ./rrp_price]
```

(or something similar) should get you all the `product` nodes which have a `search_price` child with a value which is lower than that of the value in the `rrp_price` node child.

Edit: translated into "plain English" the expression means: select any node (`//`) with the name of `product`, which has (`[` and later `]`) a child (`./`) called `search_price`, which child has a value (note that xpath silently assumes in this case that when you refer to the child, you refer to its numerical value; if that's not the case, more explicit instructions need to be issued) which is lower (`<`) than the value (same silent treatment) of another child of `product` with the name `rrp_price`.

Comment: Perfect, i understand now. Thank you for the answer and the time spent.